# * @method Users setGroups() Sets the current record's "Groups" collection

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I would like set null in all fields in one user.
If this is simple fields, for example:

```
* @method Users             setNumber()                 Sets the current record's "number" value
```

then i make:

```
$user = $query;
$user->setNumber(NULL);
$user->save();
```

this working ok, but i would like add for this

```
* @method Users            setGroups()            Sets the current record's "Groups" collection
```

but if i make:

```
$user = $query;
$user->setNumer(NULL);
$user->setUsers(NULL);
$user->save();
```

i have error:

```
Couldn't call Doctrine_Core::set(), second argument should be an instance of Doctrine_Collection when setting many-to-many references.
```

how must be the second argument for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user['Groups'] = new Doctrine_Collection('Group');
```

i.e. you're making the value an *empty collection* of Group objects